# Как сделать объект класса с встроенным отсчётом?

Tags: python

Допустим есть объект человек:

```
class Human(Alive):
    def __init__(self, name, age):  # и еще куча полей...
```

Есть число 832200. Из этого числа делается отсчёт, по его истечению поля будут перенесены в другой класс.

Я понимаю что можно сделать:

```
self.age = 832200  # понимаю что тут должно быть time_to_death

while self.age >= 0:    
    self.age = self.age - 1
```

Так вот вопросы:

1. Как привязать такой цикл к каждому объекту?
2. Наверняка есть метод по лучше, учитывая что объектов будет 500-1000
3. Как еще можно про инициировать старение в классе человек?

P.S объекты не должны удалятся...

Comment: смущает, что вы начали в заголовке "объект класса с ограниченным временем существования" и закончили в посткриптуме "объекты не должны удалятся"...

Comment: а что тогда должно происходить по окончанию "срока годности" ?

Comment: @Jack_oS Спасибо, поправил.

Comment: @n1tr0xs в плане кода, думаю будет создаваться другой объект в который будут переносится отдельные поля.

Comment: А для чего вам это нужно? То есть в каком контексте вы пытаетесь это сделать? А вообще, мне кажется, что надо записать для каждого объекта время (глобальный год, или что-то в этом роде) его создания, и просто проверять при каждом обращении к нему, что текущий "возраст" меньше определенной границы

Comment: @EzikBro то есть создать функцию допустим 
```def if_not_dead(self):
        if self.age>= 0
              print("Alive")
```
и при каждом обращение делать?

Comment: @Александр или сравнивать с системным временем, если "время пришло" - кикнуть

Comment: @Jack_oS я просто не понимаю как реализовать это сравнение для каждого экземпляра. Наверно будет логично в начале начале каждого цикла. И наверно тогда лучше подрезать цифру сделать меньше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понял вашу задачу, но каркас могу примерно следующий предложить, используя наследование и хранение всех экземпляров ваших объектов в объекте более высокого уровня:

```
import random

class Life():

    def __init__(self, age, max_age):
        self.age = age
        self.max_age = max_age

    def add_year(self):
        self.age += 1
    
    def is_alive(self):
        return self.age <= self.max_age

class Human(Life):
  
    def __init__(self, name, age):  # и еще куча полей...
        super().__init__(age, 100)
        self.name = name
  
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Человек по имени {self.name}, возраст {self.age}"

    def get_being(self):
        return self if self.is_alive() else Soul(self.name)

class Soul():
  
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Душа по имени {self.name}"

    def get_being(self):
        return self

    def add_year(self):
        pass

class Planet():
     
    def __init__(self, name, population):
         self.name = name
         self.beings = []
         for i in range(population):
             name = random.choice(["Вася", "Петя", "Света", "Надя"])
             age = random.randint(0, 100)
             self.beings.append(Human(name, age))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Текущее население планеты {self.name}\n' + '\n'.join([repr(b) for b in self.beings])

    def add_year(self):
        for b in self.beings:
            b.add_year()
        self.beings = [b.get_being() for b in self.beings]

e = Planet("Земля", 4)
print(e)
for i in range(30):
    e.add_year()
print(e)
```

Вывод:

```
Текущее население планеты Земля
Человек по имени Света, возраст 12
Человек по имени Вася, возраст 54
Человек по имени Надя, возраст 73
Человек по имени Вася, возраст 80

Текущее население планеты Земля
Человек по имени Света, возраст 42
Человек по имени Вася, возраст 84
Душа по имени Надя
Душа по имени Вася
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не совсем то что я думал, но помогло переосмыслить одну конструкцию. Я двигался не в ту сторону)